How to use Windows 11 admin rights on a default user?
I have many Windows 10/11 on a network, and I need to update a few things that require admin privs, and I have both local and network rights. Problem is I need to do modification on specific user accounts, for example editing REG require admin privs, but running a CMD as admin to do so will edit the admin's HKCU instead of the user's HKCU.
How can I run as default user with admin priv ?
I tried task scheduler with "use the following user acct : default user" with "run with highest privs" but the privs are just not there when task is launched (does this feature even do anything?).

Each user Registry hive is stored per user at %UserProfile%\NTUSER.DAT, so all you should need to do is use Reg Load to load that hive (individually for each user) at an arbitrary location like HKU\User1, make the changes, then unload the hive with Reg Unload. This is also easily scriptable, but to ensure no issues unintentionally arise, it would be highly recommend to name each User1 hive with a unique name so if any error happens to occur in the script and it doesn't unload a user hive, you're not corrupting the user profile of every subsequent user hive.

While HKEY_Users holds the Registry keys for all users on the system, and you could make the modification within HKEY_Current User with Admin permissions, regular users can actually edit  HKEY_Current User without Admin permissions:

All you need to do is Regedit as Admin, set the changes you want in the Registry, export that key to a .reg, then run that .reg from the user account that needs the changes.


thanks, that works for regedit but it was only an exemple, I have other tools with the same issue like DISM

dism modifies the entire system, there you just user admin user. Either, whatever you need to do for a user, you just do it as the user. If admin is required, then it is a system modification, and as such, you just do it as admin.

alr thanks my issue on dism isn't what I think it is then, I'll open an other thread for it.

This would be far simpler to do as a script using reg, or putting them all in a .reg file to begin with (then individually loading each user's %UserProfile%\NTUSER.DAT Registry hive, importing the changes, then unloading each hive), because unless it's changes to one key, that's going to be multiple exports.
